# change the layout of activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have two activities: a `main activity` and a `settings activity`.
I have two `layout` for my `main activity`, one for `English` and one for `Farsi`, and these two layouts are totally different. I put these two layouts in two sub folders named `layout` and `layout_fa`. When I changed the language in the settings activity all `strings` in the main activity change but the layout doesn't change until I restart the app.

**How** can I change the layout of main activity when I come back from settings activity?

**Note** : I can probably do it with `fragments` but I am looking for another way.

Comment: you should use  fragments.

Comment: isnt any way except fragments ?

Comment: no it is not, but is clean way to do it. I would suggest to finish the MainActiviy when you start the SettingsActivity, and when the user press on  the *language button" start MainActiviy again. `onCreate` read from the intent, for instance, what layout the user asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually re-create the activities once the preference has changed.

1. Save the preference in the `MainActivity`'s `onCreate`.

   ```
   private boolean mEnglishLayout;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
       mEnglishLayout = prefs.getBoolean("ENGLISH_LAYOUT", true);
       ...
   }
   ```
2. When you return from SettingsActivity, your MainActivity will call `onRestart` that's where you can watch for changes:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onRestart() {
       super.onRestart();
       SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
       boolean newLayout = prefs.getBoolean("ENGLISH_LAYOUT", true);
       if (mEnglishLayout != newLayout) {
           new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   recreate();
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```

**Note:** if all you need to do is to set a different activity layout, you can use `setContentView(R.layout.some_layout)` in place of `recreate()`.

Comment: its work but screen blink when its recreate ! is there anyway to resolve this ?

Comment: @y.feizi try `recreate` outside the handler's post method.

Answer (score 0):

Check your locale and use `setContentView` in `onResume()` method of your `main activity` class